# Populate ng model from value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am trying to populate the `ng-model` from a value, but don't want it to update until it is saved. To do this I have the following code;

Controller;

```
var SettingsController = function (roleService) {
    var ctrl = this;

    ctrl.rename = function(name) {
        ctrl.account.name = name;
    };

    roleService.role.settings().then(function (result) {
        ctrl.account = result.data.account;
    }, function (result) {
        console.log(result);
    }); 
};
```

A simple controller, it gets the current settings from a service and sets it to the ctrl.

When the `rename(name)` is called I update the name of the account (for now it just updates the scope but soon it will update also the back-end)

To rename your account I have the following piece of code

```
<input type="text" data-ng-model="account.name" />
<button type="button" data-ng-click="ctrl.rename(account.name)">
    Rename
</button>
```

*I use controler as so `ctrl` == `SettingsController`*

Now I use `data-ng-model="account.name"` to update the name. This is done so I only update the name when the button is called. The only issue is how do I get the `ctrl.account.name` value to the input, without bubbling it up.

I could add `$scope` to my controller with `$scope.account` but that seems overkill to me. Isn't there a way to copy/populate a `ng-model` from an other value or some kind?

---

To get to the controller I use the angular routerProvider;

```
$routeProvider
        .when('/settings/', {
            templateUrl: '/user/template/settings/',
            controller: 'SettingsController',
            controllerAs: 'ctrl'
        });
```

Comment: I use the routerProvider to come to the controller, so I have no `data-ng-controller`. Added the relevant routeProvider code though

Comment: If you don't want a 'live' edit then just create a copy of the object. Why make things unnecessary complicated?

Comment: <input type="text" data-ng-model="ctrl.account.name" /> ?

Comment: No he means `<input type="text" data-ng-model="ctrl.accountCopy.name" />` or some kind

Comment: when you use data-ng-model="account.name", it is sitting on the scope, so in effect you already added account to your scope, even if you're not explicitly using $scope in your controller